# Triangle of numbers on a blackboard

Tags: mathematics, blackboard

Ten rows of numbers are written on a blackboard. The first row has one $1$, the second has two $2$'s, and so on up through the tenth row with ten $10$'s:
$$
\begin{gather*}
1\\
2,\;2\\
3,\;3,\;3\\
\vdots\\
10,\;10,\ldots,\;10
\end{gather*}
$$
Choose two of the numbers on the board, erase them, and write their product divided by their sum (which will likely be a fraction). Repeat the process until only one number remains.

> What is the largest value that the remaining number could be? Also, what is the smallest value?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Notice that

$$\frac{1}{\frac{xy}{x+y}}=\frac{x+y}{xy}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$$

So the sum of the reciprocals of the numbers on the board is always preserved. The sum of the reciprocals of the numbers in each row is $1$, so the sum of all the reciprocals is $10$. Therefore, the last number left must be $\frac{1}{10}$.

Comment: I want to point out the general idea here that also solves [this problem](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/7862/4551): apply a transformation to the numbers so that the combining operation on the transformed numbers is commutative and associative. Here, inverting makes the operation be addition, and there, adding 1 makes the operation be multiplication.